# Negative relative positioning puts extra space

Tags: css

http://ahjer-ahjer.blogspot.com/

This is my first time here...

Please refer to the source of the site above. I have a problem with removing the extra space on the bottom of the page. I believe it's caused by the negative relative positions I've made but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Should I change my codes in any way?

Another minor problem is that for IE, the text "If you're bored, reload the page to see the different personalities of Jeremy!" appears lower than in Firefox. Is there anyway to solve this problem too?

IN FACT!!! I have a feeling I have coded all this wrongly. I think I have used too much negative relative positioning :( Is there a better way? Argh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The link is not working but yes, relative positioning moves the visible content but keeps its position in the flow so that a "gap" stays. You could use a negative margin-top instead.